# SyntaxError on print function in python

Tags: python, printing

I'm following an online guide for making text adventures.

They have an action that looks like this:

```
<p>def you_quit(why):</p>
<p>       print(f"{why}. You_quit!") </p>
<p>       exit(0)  </p>
```

But when I go to run the program I get an invalid syntax error with the little carrot pointing at the second quotation mark. Like this:

```
<p>print(f"{why}. You_quit!") </p>  
<p>------------------------------------^</p>
```

I've been fiddling around but I can't get the code to run without the code messing up when I get to this line. I'm almost positive it has something to do with the f, but the guide doesn't explain the purpose of the f.

Any help would be appreciated and if the formatting is messed up its cause I'm on mobile. Sorry.

Comment: Beware of mobile keyboard's auto-capitalise feature. `Def` -> `def`.

Comment: @Austin thanks! I thought I had caught them all.

Comment: @Redpenrev the function itself is fine. It's something before that that's causing the syntax error

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `f` are supported in newer versions (3.6+).

Comment: @gmds that's what I thought at first because I'd had a similar syntax error elsewhere where I had forgotten to close parens in the previous line, but in this case that is literally the first three lines of my program.

Comment: @Austin I'm not sure actually. Whatever one was pre installed on Macs circa 2015. Probably 2.10, I'm like 90% positive it's not 3 or later.

Comment: @Sean Francis N. Ballais unfortunately my mom just had me shut everything down cause it's late. Assuming it's not version 3 and is instead an earlier version: what's the purpose of 'f' and what did it replace in earlier versions? I guess what I'm trying to ask is what can I Google to figure out how to solve my error?

Comment: That's a *caret*, not a "carrot".

Comment: @tripleee ok! Thank you!

Comment: @Redpenrev Run `import sys; sys.version_info`, or `python --version`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `Def` to `def` and don't forget the indent(four spaces) in **Python**.

Change your code to this:

```
def so(why):
    print(f"{why}.You quit!")
    exit(0)
```

And run it!
To run it, write:

```
so("You didn't try!")
```

Here you setting the value to `why`

**Output:**

> You didn't try! You quit!

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this and research so() more!

Comment: @Redpenrev All the best. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the version you are using and the guide is using are different. It is apparent that the guide is using Python 3.6 or later, and since you are on a Mac, you are using Python 2.7. Based on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264056/is-python-pre-installed-on-every-mac-version) post, the version you are using is likely Python 2.7.10 (and not 2.10 as you have said in the comments).

To solve your issue, you would need to use install Python 3. You can install Python 3 by using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

```
brew install python3
```

Once it is installed, you can run your code using

```
python3 <your-script>.py
```

However, if you intend on remaining with Python 2 (which is not recommended since [Python 2.7 will only have a few months left of support](https://pythonclock.org/)), you will have to use what I would call classic string formatting tools as discussed in [Yash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55428881/1116098).

---

In the comments, you asked

> What's the purpose of 'f' and what did it replace in earlier versions?

**TL;DR: f-strings offer a simpler way of formatting strings. It does not replace the previous string formatting tools.**

*f-strings* came from [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/). It allows embedding expressions inside string literals in as minimal of a syntax as possible. Simply put, it is just another way of formatting strings, but with the added benefit of running expressions inside those strings. You define an f-string by prefixing an `f` to a string literal.

For example, you want to compute the area of a triangle and print it out. Pre-3.6, you would have done something like

```
print('Area of a triangle: {}'.format((base * height) / 2))
```

With f-strings, you can just use

```
print(f'Area of a triangle: {(base * height) / 2}')
```

A whole lot simpler!

In essence, f-strings just provide a simpler way of string formatting. The PEP also states that it does not intend on replacing `%`-format and `format()`. I reckon this is for backward compatibility.